# Facebook Sharing Image with specific image on Wordpress Post

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I'm trying to solve the issue of adding a picture to my shared links on Facebook, and this picture is supposed to be the one with the img class "hpic" in my post.

So, I've been wondering if it is possible to add this code....

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="img class 'hpic' on the post" />
```

But how do I reference it?

**EDIT**: I need it to automatically get the picture link for **different** blog posts, I only want to know how to find and reference the 'hpic' tag.

Comment: check this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/#images

Answer (score 1):

The `og:image` tag content needs to be the URL of the image. It should look like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

More info about open graph can be read here: http://ogp.me/

**Easy WordPress Solution**

If you do not want to write code, a convenient option for WordPress is to use the Yoast SEO plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) to set custom Open Graph tags. Here is an article about how to do that: https://kb.yoast.com/kb/custom-open-graph-tags/

Comment: Yes, I know it's supposed to be the image link, but I do not know what to write to get the automatic link for every blog post. Since it's different blog posts, I only have the 'hpic' tag to go after.

Comment: I have found that it is easier to use Yoast SEO to manually set the image on each page. If this is not an option then you will need to write PHP to get that image URL and set it in your header.

Comment: Will try Yoast. Thank you! :)